# C Program skips a line

Tags: c, while-loop, stdin

so when I'm prompted to enter a value for p, if I enter too little characters, it brings me to the next line and not the next prompt. If I enter a large enough input it works fine. Also, my re-running of the program seems to not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
   char pbuffer[10], qbuffer[10], kbuffer[10];
   int p=0, q=0, k=0;
   int r, i, Q, c, count, sum;
   char a[3];
   a[0]='y';

   while(a[0]=='y' || a[0]=='Y')
   {
      printf("Enter a p value: \n");
      fgets(pbuffer, sizeof(pbuffer), stdin);
      while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
      p = strtol(pbuffer, (char **)NULL, 10);

      printf("Enter a q value: \n");
      fgets(qbuffer, sizeof(qbuffer), stdin);
      while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
      q = strtol(qbuffer, (char **)NULL, 10);

      printf("Enter a k value: \n");
      fgets(kbuffer, sizeof(kbuffer), stdin);
      while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
      k = strtol(kbuffer, (char **)NULL, 10);

      while(p<q+1)
      {
         Q=p;
         sum=0;
         count=0;
         while(Q>0)
         {
            count++;
            r = Q%10;
            sum = sum + pow(r,k);
            Q = Q/10;
         }

         if ( p == sum && i>1 && count==k )
         {
            printf("%d\n",p);

         }
         p++;
         a[0]='z';
      }
      while((a[0]!='y') && (a[0]='Y') && (a[0]!='n') && (a[0]!='N'))
      {
         printf("Would you like to run again? (y/n) ");
         fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
      }
      while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 Enter a p value:
 1
 1
 Enter a q value:
 1000
 0
```

Comment: Your program and output don't match.  It's not the issue you describe in the question either, there is more output than there is program.

Comment: It's exactly the output I'm getting for that input. I took a picture, but I cant post it right now with my little rep.

Comment: Then your posted code is out of date.  You're not printing the values you read, but there are 2 numbers between your prompts.  When I run this code verbatim, it prints something different.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a mistake in the code line

```
while((a[0]!='y') && (a[0]='Y') && (a[0]!='n') && (a[0]!='N'))
```

You have missed the '!' character in second condition
 And for your question, what is the reason to use this line:

```
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

if we work with console it just wait for one more '\n'
because the previous one was taken by fgets